# Problem to contact outside URLs from within docker container

Tags: docker

We are running sitecore with docker in version 10.1.2 (rev. 006578).

Inside the cm container, we consume a web service from a server inside the intranet. We are part of the intranet via VPN, using Check Point End Point Security. The service responds, but with great delay of about 20 seconds. If we call the service from the host machine, the response is less than 1 second.

On the host machine, tracert 192.168.7.144 results in:

[image]

But from the container CM's CLI prompt, we get:

[image]

The first hop always has a timeout, then followed by success with normal response times.

It seems like the problem is not specific to the intranet. If we try the same thing from within docker to a public website, the same timeout in the first hops:

[image]

The problem is the same in any of our docker containers.

A solution or any hint to point us into the right direction are more than welcome!